# SwipeToRefreshLayout Refreshing Function Won't Work Properly

Tags: android, refresh, swiperefreshlayout

To begin with, I checked literally every single SwipeToRefreshLayout question to solve this issue, but none worked for me. So I'm asking for your help to solve this issue.
I want the refresher to go away "once the refreshing is complete". What I tried so far either made it go away too early, or not go away at all. Here is the related code: (note that mSwipeRefreshLayout is already defined.)

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    final double latitude = 39.9179;
    final double longitude = 32.8627;

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            handler.post(refreshing);
            getForecast(latitude, longitude);
        }

    });
    getForecast(latitude, longitude);
}
private final Runnable refreshing = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {

            if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
                handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }else{
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

and the data fetch function:

```
private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
    String apiKey = "7d22cdb138cd70f2e9e8d2006cd0461c";
    String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey
            + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

    if (isNetworkAvailable()){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(forecastUrl).build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            alertUserAboutError();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    mCurrentWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateDisplay();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
            }
        }
    });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               getForecast(latitude, longitude); //call ur function here 

                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Even though this solution is correct in many cases, it does not solve mine. Refresher still goes away before the data comes.

Comment: It may be because you are fetching your data Asynchronously.. check your data retreival function then